# C++ - Ingame Text Under Eachother in Loop

Tags: c++, menu, game-engine

I'm developing a game modification for GTAV, but I got stuck. I want to display options on the screen using a loop and I kinda got that working, but it isn't displaying correctly.

This is what code I'm using to display the text:

```
void DRAW_TEXT(char* text, float x, float y, float s_x, float s_y, int font, bool outline, bool Shadow, bool center, bool RightJustify, int r, int g, int b, int a){
    UI::SET_TEXT_COLOUR(r, g, b, a);
    UI::SET_TEXT_DROPSHADOW(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (outline) UI::SET_TEXT_OUTLINE();
    UI::SET_TEXT_FONT(font);
    UI::SET_TEXT_CENTRE(center);
    UI::SET_TEXT_RIGHT_JUSTIFY(RightJustify);
    UI::SET_TEXT_SCALE(s_x, s_y);
    UI::BEGIN_TEXT_COMMAND_DISPLAY_TEXT(STRING);
    UI::ADD_TEXT_COMPONENT_SUBSTRING_PLAYER_NAME(text);
    UI::END_TEXT_COMMAND_DISPLAY_TEXT(x, y);
}
```

Then I loop it like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < optionCount; i++) {
    if (i == selectedIndex) {
        DRAW_TEXT(MenuOptions[i], 0.169 + (0.230 * (i / 3)), 0.228 + (0.040 * (i / 3)), 0.35, 0.35, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    } else {
        DRAW_TEXT(MenuOptions[i], 0.169 + (0.230 * (i / 3)), 0.228 + (0.040 * (i / 3)), 0.35, 0.35, 0, false, false, false, false, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    }
}
```

The outcome of that is like this:

[image]

How can I make it so it displays all the options under eachother instead of next to eachother like so:

```
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
etc..
```

Comment: That's not any c++ standard functionality. You might consider adding more relevant tags please.

Comment: @TheDude Something like this? I really don't know anything else I should add..

Comment: If anybody can help out, it would be **greatly** appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're using `i / 3` expression, which won't work as you expected unless you cast `i` to floating-point type. You need to use something like this:

```
DRAW_TEXT(MenuOptions[i], 0.169 + (0.230 * ((double)i / 3)), 0.228 + (0.040 * ((double)i / 3)), 0.35, 0.35, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, 0, 0, 255);
```

Comment: Hi Denis, thanks a lot for your answer. However, it's not the exact desired result as it displays like this: https://i.imgur.com/tTR7gHJ.png

Comment: Well, you can play with constants to achieve what you want. I bet `DRAW_TEXT(MenuOptions[i], 0.169, 0.228 + (0.060 * ((double)i / 3)), 0.35, 0.35, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, 0, 0, 255);` is almost correct. Try to adjust those values and see what changes.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!